# How many gates are in the $ k $ level of single qubit Clifford hierarchy?

Tags: mathematics, clifford-group, clifford-hierarchy

Define the single qubit Clifford hierarchy recursively by
$$
\mathcal{C}^1:=<iX,iZ>
$$
the determinaint 1 subgroup of the Pauli group. Define the rest of the the hierarchy inductively by
$$
\mathcal{C}^k:=\{ V \in SU_2: VpV^{-1} \text{for all } p \in \mathcal{C}^{k-1} \} 
$$

How many elements are in $ \mathcal{C}^k $? I know
$$
C^1=<iX,iZ>
$$
has size $ 8 $. And
$$
C^2=<iH,\overline{\zeta_8}P>
$$
has $ 48 $ elements. How many elements does $ \mathcal{C}^3 $ have?

Here $ X $ is pauli $ X $, $ Z $ is Pauli $ Z $, $ H $ is Hadamard, and $ P=diag(1,i) $ is the phase gate.

Comment: As I indicated in my other answer, it should be possible to have an elementary counting argument for the third level. For higher levels, you may use that all elements in the Clifford hierarchy *for a single qubit* are semi-Clifford, so you can take the (known) order of the diagonal Clifford hierarchy, multiply that with the squared order of the Clifford group and mod out the stabilizer. I think this should give you the right cardinality

Comment: +1 that sounds very promising. I'll try to work out some counting with semi Clifford for some small cases for $ n=1 $ and $ n=2 $ qubits. So is counting the number of elements pretty hopeless for $ n \geq 3, k \geq 3 $ since no one knows much about the structure of the hierarchy for those values?

Comment: Yeah, I think there's not much hope to count them, we don't know enough.